# change navigation bar background using my own image

Tags: iphone, background, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller

i want to change navigation bar background using my own image, but i really dont know what to do. i was search it on google, but some samples tell in navigationbar template. my application is a split view base. How could i do that??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change the background of the navigation bar that too without using category, this might be helpful to give that feel, see if it fulfills your need:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

        UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
        //here for v, width= navBar width and height=navBar height

    [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"]]];

    [self.view addSubview:v];

    [v release];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer... i was try this too, and it's done too :)
using this answer, make me change different navigation bar background, using different image :)

Answer (score 2):

```
#import "ImageViewController.h"

@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
implement this code in your .m file


@implementation ImageViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    UIImageView *backGroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:backGroundView atIndex:0];
    [backGroundView release];
}

@end
```

Comment: guys...i was try your code, but without implement the category in viewDidLoad method, tha background is still displayed.. is that something wrong?? i'm sorry, my comprehension is still low

Comment: guys...i understand know..customization at that category make every navigation bar's background in this application change into image that define there. So, if i have 3 navigation bar, each background have a same background. But if i want to change it and make each background different, what should i do ??? i try to define in each viewDidLoad, but each background just show the tintColor, not the image...what should I do???

Answer (score 2):

You can add the image directly in the navigation bar background with the code below

`[navigation_bar  setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

Answer (score 0):

To add a background image to UINavigationBar, you need to create a category that extends UINavigationBar. Just find the below given code and add it into your implementation file.

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"background.png"];
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

After implementing it.. you can call it anywhere within your application and you can see the change on every view. Do not forget to add image into your resources folder.

Comment: you can add this code in implementation file of yourViewController before @implementation